# How can i query update of a custom field within last 100 days in Jira (JQL)

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I have a custom filed as "SIB".
i want to query all the bugs that have updated "SIB" in last 100 days.

I tried few things like

1. CHANGED (doesn't works with my field)
2. updated > -100d (gives all the bugs but i need only bugs that have updated "SIB")

I was trying to work with "issueFunction and dateCompare" but not sure what sub query should be used.

Comment: Is it one-time thing or do you need as automated process?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with JQL.

But if you wneed this information many times, you can use automation.
To do that, you can create a **date type custom field** named "**SIB updated**" (this field should be hidden). After that, you can create an automation that triggered when the field "**SIB**" was updated. And update the new custom field "SIB updated" with the current date. So with the JQL **"SIB updated" > -100d**, you can get the query that you want.